# Every tree is cordial

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a labelling $f:V(G)\to \{ 0,1\}$ of a graph $G$ and the induced edge-labelling $f^* :E(G)\to \{ 0,1\}$ by $f^* (uv)=|f(u)-f(v)|$. $f$ is called a cordial labelling if the following condition is satified: $$\vert v_f (1)-v_f (0)\vert \leq1, \quad \vert e_{f^*}(1)-e_{f^*}(0)\vert \leq 1,$$ where $v_f (i)$ and $e_{f^*}(i)$, $i=0,1$, is the number of vertices and edges of $G$, respectively, with label $i$ (under $f$ and $f^*$, respectively).

I. Cahit proved in his paper that every tree is cordial.

The proof is: We use induction on $n$, the number of vertices. Let $n\geq 3$, and assume that all trees with $m<n$ vertices are cordial. Let $T$ be any tree with $n$ vertices, and let $w$ be any end-vertex on a maximum length path in $T$. Let $e_1 =\{ z,w\}$ be the end-edge incident with $w$. If there exists another end-edge $e_2 =\{ z,y\}$ incident with $z$, delete from $T$ vertices $w,y$ and $e_1 ,e_2$. The resulting  tree $T'$ has $n-2$ vertices, and so by the  induction hypothesis it admits a cordial labelling, say, $f$. Define now a labelling $f^*$ of $T$ by $f^* (x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in V(T')$, $f^*(w)=0$, $f^* (y)=1$. Clearly, $f^*$ is a cordial labelling of $T$.

If there is no such end-edge  $e_2$, there must be an edge $e_3 =\{ z,u\}$ (here $u$ is not an ende-vertex). Delete from $T$ vertices $w,z$ and edges $e_1 ,e_3$ obtaining a tree $T_1$, $\ldots$.

I understood when there exists another end-edge $e_2 =\{ z,y\}$, but what about $e_3$? I was wondering if someone could draw me a graph with $e_3$ in it.

[image]

Comment: Very close to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4388183/305862 Why don't you mention it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete $y$ and $e_2$ from your picture, then the second case applies and $e_3$ is the remaining unlabeled edge incident on $z$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much for your help.